# Main body of website is not aligned with the background image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is my website [swimbikerun.ph](http://www.swimbikerun.ph)

I've been trying everything really hard to center the main body of my website but I just can't seen to make it work.

Here's what I have so far.

```
body {      
  background: #000000
 url('http://www.swimbikerun.ph/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/finalbgtakeover.png') center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;   
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header-yadh {
  width: 720px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#footer-yadh {
  width: 720px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 764px;
  max-width: 1095px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  .feedtwitter {
    float:right;
  }
  .rightoo-banner {
    float:right;
  }     
  .leftoo-banner {
    width:300px; 
    float:left
  }
}
```

I got it right in my forum (main page aligns perfectly with background image takeover. I'm trying to replicate the codes but it just won't work. It should look like my online forum (cannot post 2 links yet)

I know I'm one CSS code away from getting everything into proper alignment.

I also need to align it on ipad and android phones and tablets.

How can I do this ?

Comment: .span-24{width:950px;} define in your css

Comment: I added the suggested .span-24 and defined it in the css which got my website centered. but the problem is, the right sidebar went underneath the website? Here is a screenshot of the site now

http://i1206.photobucket.com/albums/bb442/igopenterprise/newcenter_zps1a53a08d.png

Answer (score 0):

Now Define your **css** `.span-24` `{width:950px;}`

**As like this**

```
.span-24{
  width:950px;
}
```

Comment: Hi I defined the .span-24 which got my site centered. But the problem is, the right sidebar disappeared and went under my website.

here is a screenshot of the site now.

[link]http://i1206.photobucket.com/albums/bb442/igopenterprise/newcenter_zps1a53a08d.png[/link]

Answer (score 0):

looking at your website, the `.container` has width: 950px, but your `.span-24, div.span-24` has a width of 1100px which messed up the width of the `.content-wrap`.

changing the width of the `.span-24, div.span-24` to 950px will fix the problem

Comment: Hi Aister I did this and changed the span to 950px. It did center the website but the right sidebar disappeared and appeared at the bottom of the website?

Comment: remove the `.span-24, div.span-24` css, and change the css of `.container` to 1100px

Comment: @user946250 make sure u get the comment